# Convert multidimensional array into single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is multidimensional for no reason

```
/* This is how my array is currently */
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [plan] => basic
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [plan] => small
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [plan] => novice
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [plan] => professional
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [plan] => master
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [plan] => promo
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [plan] => newplan
            )

    )

 )
```

I want to convert this array into this form

```
/*Now, I want to simply it down to this*/
Array (
[0] => basic
[1] => small
[2] => novice
[3] => professional
[4] => master
[5] => promo
[6] => newplan
)
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: It is that way for no reason? Instead of changing the array, is there a way to simply create the array differently in the first place?

Comment: Hope this will helpful to you,

$array=[
    0 => [
        0 => ['plan' => 'basic'],

        1 => ['plan' => 'small'],

        2 => ['plan' => 'novice'],

        3 => ['plan' => 'professional'],

        4 => ['plan' => 'master'],

        5 => ['plan' => 'promo'],

        6 => ['plan' => 'newplan']
    ]
 ];
$arr=[];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($k){global $arr; $arr[]=$k;});
print_r($arr);

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Assuming this array may or may not be redundantly nested and you're unsure of how deep it goes, this should flatten it for you:

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 135):

This single line would do that:

```php
$array = array_column($array, 'plan');
```

The first argument is an array | The second argument is an array key.

For details, go to official documentation: **https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php**.

Comment: Nice, but requires PHP 5 >= 5.5.0: https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: its only useful when you want value from specific keys

Comment: @devnull-Ψ That's what he asks in the question.

Answer (score 30):

If you come across a multidimensional array that is pure data, like this one below, then you can use a single call to array_merge() to do the job via reflection:

```
$arrayMult = [ ['a','b'] , ['c', 'd'] ];
$arraySingle = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arrayMult);
// $arraySingle is now = ['a','b', 'c', 'd'];
```

Comment: If anyone needs to learn more about 'call_user_func_array', here is the link to documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: You can do it with `$arraySingle = array_merge(...$arrayMult);`

Comment: @Peacefull I see that you are using PHPStorm in the right manner!

Answer (score 15):

Just assign it to it's own first element:

```
$array = $array[0];
```

Comment: @Usman Ahmed Look at the original array again. All seven elements are inside an array with only one element.

Comment: This will output:
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [plan] => basic
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [plan] => small
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [plan] => novice
            )
    )

This is not what he want.

Comment: It will return following array, which is not user want.

Comment: Time for an edit @Paul this answer is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

For this particular case, this'll do:

```
$array = array_map('current', $array[0]);
```

It's basically the exact same question is this one, look at some answers there: [PHP array merge from unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747619/php-array-merge-from-unknown-number-of-parameters/).

Comment: It works not only for array '0' element but also for any array. Thanks, It works bro @deceze

Answer (score 8):

```
 $singleArray = array();

    foreach ($multiDimensionalArray as $key => $value){
        $singleArray[$key] = $value['plan'];
    }
```

this is best way to create a array from multiDimensionalArray  array.

thanks

Answer (score 8):

Problem array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "id" => 8
      "name" => "Veggie Burger"
      "image" => ""
      "Category_type" => "product"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "id" => 9
      "name" => "Veggie Pitta"
      "image" => ""
      "Category_type" => "product"
    ]
    2 => array:4 [▼
      "id" => 10
      "name" => "Veggie Wrap"
      "image" => ""
      "Category_type" => "product"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "id" => 18
      "name" => "Cans 330ml"
      "image" => ""
      "Category_type" => "product"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "id" => 19
      "name" => "Bottles 1.5 Ltr"
      "image" => ""
      "Category_type" => "product"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Solution array:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 8
    "name" => "Veggie Burger"
    "image" => ""
    "Category_type" => "product"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 9
    "name" => "Veggie Pitta"
    "image" => ""
    "Category_type" => "product"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "name" => "Veggie Wrap"
    "image" => ""
    "Category_type" => "product"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 18
    "name" => "Cans 330ml"
    "image" => ""
    "Category_type" => "product"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 19
    "name" => "Bottles 1.5 Ltr"
    "image" => ""
    "Category_type" => "product"
  ]
]
```

Write this code and get your solution , `$subcate` is your multi dimensional array.

```
$singleArrayForCategory = array_reduce($subcate, 'array_merge', array());
```

Answer (score 5):

none of answers helped me, in case when I had several levels of nested arrays. the solution is almost same as @AlienWebguy already did, but with tiny difference.

```
function nestedToSingle(array $array)
{
    $singleDimArray = [];

    foreach ($array as $item) {

        if (is_array($item)) {
            $singleDimArray = array_merge($singleDimArray, nestedToSingle($item));

        } else {
            $singleDimArray[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $singleDimArray;
}
```

test example

```
$array = [
        'first',
        'second',
        [
            'third',
            'fourth',
        ],
        'fifth',
        [
            'sixth',
            [
                'seventh',
                'eighth',
                [
                    'ninth',
                    [
                        [
                            'tenth'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'eleventh'
            ]
        ],
        'twelfth'
    ];

    $array = nestedToSingle($array);
    print_r($array);

    //output
    array:12 [
        0 => "first"
        1 => "second"
        2 => "third"
        3 => "fourth"
        4 => "fifth"
        5 => "sixth"
        6 => "seventh"
        7 => "eighth"
        8 => "ninth"
        9 => "tenth"
        10 => "eleventh"
        11 => "twelfth"
   ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your sample array has 3 levels. Because the first level has only `[0]`, you can hardcode your access into it and avoid an extra function/construct call.

([Code Demos](https://3v4l.org/7jKGq))

1. **array_walk_recursive()** is handy and versatile, but for this task may be overkill and certainly a bit more convoluted in terms of readability.

   ```
   array_walk_recursive($array, function($leafvalue)use(&$flat){$flat[] = $leafvalue;});
   var_export($flat);
   ```
2. If this was my code, I'd be using **array_column()** because it is direct and speaks literally about the action being performed.

   ```
   var_export(array_column($array[0], 'plan'));
   ```
3. Of course **a couple of `foreach() loops** will perform very efficiently because language constructs generally perform more efficiently than function calls.

   ```
   foreach ($array[0] as $plans) {
       foreach ($plans as $value) {
           $flat[] = $value;
       }
   }
   var_export($flat);
   ```
4. Finally, as a funky alternative (which I can't imagine actually putting to use unless I was writing code for someone whom I didn't care for) I'll offer an **array_merge_recursive() call with a splat operator** (`...`).

   ```
   var_export(array_merge_recursive(...$array[0])['plan']);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just using a loop.

```
    $singleArray = array();

    foreach ($multiDimensionalArray as $key => $value){
        $singleArray[$key] = $value['plan'];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently I've been using AlienWebguy's array_flatten function but it gave me a problem that was very hard to find the cause of.
array_merge causes problems, and this isn't the first time that I've made problems with it either. 
If you have the same array keys in one inner array that you do in another, then the later values will overwrite the previous ones in the merged array.

Here's a different version of array_flatten without using array_merge:

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $arrayList=array_flatten($value);
      foreach ($arrayList as $listItem) {
        $result[] = $listItem; 
      }
    } 
   else { 
    $result[$key] = $value; 
   } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite that `array_column` will work nice here, in case you need to *flatten* any array no matter of it's internal structure you can use this [array library](https://github.com/minwork/array) to achieve it without ease:

```php
$flattened = Arr::flatten($array);
```

which will produce exactly the array you want.

Comment: This answer is specific to Laravel. We have `array_flatten` helper function in laravel or the above mentioned method using the macros.

Answer (score 3):

This simple code you can use

```
$array = array_column($array, 'value', 'key');
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in most voted answer. Here is the correct version.

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}
```

The difference is on the line `$result[] = $value;`

Original answer was `$result[$key] = $value;`
The $key index is incorrect after flattering any array in the cycle.

Comment: You could mention what the error is and how you have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I described the error and the fix in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following this pattern

```
$input = array(10, 20, array(30, 40), array('key1' => '50', 'key2'=>array(60), 70));
```

Call the function :

```
echo "<pre>";print_r(flatten_array($input, $output=null));
```

Function Declaration :

```
function flatten_array($input, $output=null) {
if($input == null) return null;
if($output == null) $output = array();
foreach($input as $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $output = flatten_array($value, $output);
    } else {
        array_push($output, $value);
    }
}
return $output;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've written a complement to the accepted answer. In case someone, like myself need a prefixed version of the keys, this can be helpful.

```
Array
(
    [root] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://localhost/misc/markia
        )

)
```

```
Array
(
    [root.url] => http://localhost/misc/markia
)
```

```php
<?php
function flattenOptions($array, $old = '') {
  if (!is_array($array)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $result = array_merge($result, flattenOptions($value, $key));
    }
    else {
      $result[$old . '.' . $key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had come across the same requirement to flatter multidimensional array into single dimensional array than search value using text in key. here is my code

```
$data = '{
    "json_data": [{
            "downtime": true,
            "pfix": {
                "max": 100,
                "threshold": 880
            },
            "ints": {
                "int": [{
                    "rle": "pri",
                    "device": "laptop",
                    "int": "Ether3",
                    "ip": "127.0.0.3"
                }],
                "eth": {
                    "lan": 57
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "downtime": false,
            "lsi": "987654",
            "pfix": {
                "min": 10000,
                "threshold": 890
            },
            "mana": {
                "mode": "NONE"
            },
            "ints": {
                "int": [{
                    "rle": "sre",
                    "device": "desk",
                    "int": "Ten",
                    "ip": "1.1.1.1",
                    "UF": true
                }],
                "ethernet": {
                    "lan": 2
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
';

$data = json_decode($data,true);


$stack = &$data;
$separator = '.';
$toc = array();

while ($stack) {
    list($key, $value) = each($stack);
    unset($stack[$key]);
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $build = array($key => ''); # numbering without a title.
        foreach ($value as $subKey => $node)
            $build[$key . $separator . $subKey] = $node;
        $stack = $build + $stack;
        continue;
    }
    if(!is_numeric($key)){
        $toc[$key] = $value;
    }
}


echo '<pre/>';
print_r($toc);
```

My output:

```
Array
(
    [json_data] => 
    [json_data.0] => 
    [json_data.0.downtime] => 1
    [json_data.0.pfix] => 
    [json_data.0.pfix.max] => 100
    [json_data.0.pfix.threshold] => 880
    [json_data.0.ints] => 
    [json_data.0.ints.int] => 
    [json_data.0.ints.int.0] => 
    [json_data.0.ints.int.0.rle] => pri
    [json_data.0.ints.int.0.device] => laptop
    [json_data.0.ints.int.0.int] => Ether3
    [json_data.0.ints.int.0.ip] => 127.0.0.3
    [json_data.0.ints.eth] => 
    [json_data.0.ints.eth.lan] => 57
    [json_data.1] => 
    [json_data.1.downtime] => 
    [json_data.1.lsi] => 987654
    [json_data.1.pfix] => 
    [json_data.1.pfix.min] => 10000
    [json_data.1.pfix.threshold] => 890
    [json_data.1.mana] => 
    [json_data.1.mana.mode] => NONE
    [json_data.1.ints] => 
    [json_data.1.ints.int] => 
    [json_data.1.ints.int.0] => 
    [json_data.1.ints.int.0.rle] => sre
    [json_data.1.ints.int.0.device] => desk
    [json_data.1.ints.int.0.int] => Ten
    [json_data.1.ints.int.0.ip] => 1.1.1.1
    [json_data.1.ints.int.0.UF] => 1
    [json_data.1.ints.ethernet] => 
    [json_data.1.ints.ethernet.lan] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my contribuition

```
function arrayUnica($array, $prefix = "")
{
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    }
    $new_array = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $key = is_int($key) ? $prefix . $key . "-" : $key . "_";
            $new_array = array_merge($new_array, arrayUnica($value, $key));
        } else {
            $new_array[$prefix . $key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helpful for you,

```
$array= 'YOUR_MULTIDIMENSIONAL_ARRAY';
$arr=[];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($k){global $arr; $arr[]=$k;});
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done this with OOP style

```
$res=[1=>[2,3,7,8,19],3=>[4,12],2=>[5,9],5=>6,7=>[10,13],10=>[11,18],8=>[14,20],12=>15,6=>[16,17]];
class MultiToSingle{
public $result=[];
public function __construct($array){
    if(!is_array($array)){
        echo "Give a array";
    }
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
                $this->result[]=$value[$i];
            }  
        }else{
            $this->result[]=$value;
        }
    }
}
}

$obj= new MultiToSingle($res);
$array=$obj->result;
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Multi dimensional array to single array with one line code !!!
Enjoy the code.

```
$array=[1=>[2,5=>[4,2],[7,8=>[3,6]],5],4];
$arr=[];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($k){global $arr; $arr[]=$k;});
print_r($arr);
```

...Enjoy the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it works for me:

```
    $newArray = array();
            foreach($operator_call_logs as $array) {
                foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
                    $newArray[$k] = $v;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? What does `$operator_call_logs` contain?

Answer (score -2):

**Save this as a php file, simply import and use single_array() function**

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['single_array']=[];
function array_conveter($array_list){
    if(is_array($array_list)){
        foreach($array_list as $array_ele){
            if(is_array($array_ele)){
                array_conveter($array_ele);
            }else{
                array_push($GLOBALS['single_array'],$array_ele);
            }
        }
    }else{
        array_push($GLOBALS['single_array'],$array_list);
    }
}
function single_array($mix){
    foreach($mix as $single){
        array_conveter($single);
    }return $GLOBALS['single_array'];
    $GLOBALS['single_array']=[];
}
/* Example convert your multi array to single  */
$mix_array=[3,4,5,[4,6,6,7],'abc'];
print_r(single_array($mix_array));

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

if use **php version 7.4** and above

```
$users = [
    [
        'Ahmed',
        'Mohammed',
    ],
    [
        'Saeed',
        'Rami',
        'Haider',
    ],
];

$admin = array_merge(...$users);
```

Comment: [Nope](https://3v4l.org/94F76)