# Php - array_chunk add text according with the key value and output it to a file

Tags: php, arrays, forms, output

I am relatively new with php and am in need of some help.

I have a html form, when the user can submit the text. This text is processed by php, and if there is a line with more than 20 characters, happens a line break.
After, all text is "exploded", and I get an array. So far all is well.

```
function hexToStr($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;}

    $format = $_POST['format'];
    $title= strtoupper($_POST['titre']);
    $txtcontent = $_POST['texte'];
    $txtcontent =  wordwrap($txtcontent,20,hexToStr('0D0A'),true);
    $txtcontent = explode("\n", $txtcontent);

print_r(array_chunk($txtcontent, 9, false));



$filecontent = implode(array_chunk($txtcontent, 9, false)); 

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$_POST['titre'].'.'.$format.'');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

//$fh = fopen($filename, 'wb');
$fh = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fwrite($fh, $filecontent);
fclose($fh);
```

Im using array_chunk to separate the array $txtcontent in arrays chunk with 9 elements.

Now, I need add some constant text at the beginning and end of each new array element, according to the key value.
Maybe i need to do a loop or something like it, I've tried many times and still can not.
I need help to do this.

Exemple:
If i submit this text in the web form:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
```

i will have:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => line1 [1] => line2 [2] => line3 [3] => line4 [4] => line5 [5] => line6 [6] => line7 [7] => line8 [8] => line9 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => line10 [1] => line11 [2] => line12 ) )
```

This is where I need help:

After process it (after adding constant text, according to the key value), it should be something like it. However i dont know how i can do it.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[0] => \Text 1,1,"line1"
[1] => \Text 7,1,"line2"
[2] => \Text 13,1,"line3"
[3] => \Text 19,1,"line4"
[4] => \Text 25,1,"line5"
[5] => \Text 31,1,"line6"
[6] => \Text 37,1,"line7"
[7] => \Text 43,1,"line8"
[8] => \Text 49,1,"line9"
) [1] => Array ( 
[0] => \Text 1,1,"line10"
[1] => \Text 7,1,"line11"
[2] => \Text 13,1,"line12"
) )
```

Finnaly, when i output it to the file, I shall have:

(I dont know how to output array_chunk, i also need help to do this.)

```
\Text 1,1,"line1"
\Text 7,1,"line2"
\Text 13,1,"line3"
\Text 19,1,"line4"
\Text 25,1,"line5"
\Text 31,1,"line6"
\Text 37,1,"line7"
\Text 43,1,"line8"
\Text 49,1,"line9"
\Text 1,1,"line10"
\Text 7,1,"line11"
\Text 13,1,"line12"
```

**Note** that the element numbers in array may be larger or smaller, this is only a exemple.

**Note** also that arrays with same key (exemple: line 1 and 10) will have the same extra text at the end and beggin.

I think this question is quite hard, but I hope someone can help me. I'm already a week ago trying to solve it and I still can not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps, but this question is a lot to take in:

You can do a foreach loop on the multidimensional array you make with array_chunk, and add the text that you want to add like this:

```
$chunkedarray = array_chunk($txtcontent, 9, false);
foreach($chunkedarray as $key => $array){
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        $chunkedarray[$key][$k] = '\text '.($k*6+1).',1,'.$v;
    }
}
```

Then you can flatten the multi dimensional array with a function I found from @alienwebguy on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array#answer-6785366):

```
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
} 
$flattenedarray = array_flatten($chunkedarray);
```

Then you can output the flattened multidimensional array with another for loop:

```
foreach($flattenedarray as $v){
  echo $v.'<br>';
}
```

Check out the example code on IDEone.com: http://ideone.com/vzPJOB