# show distinct result from two array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays...

1) how could i get only the different key->value one?
2) how can i insert to mysql the second array?

```
// first array
$aa =  Array
            (
                [t_a] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [f_c] => LAL
                                [p_r] => RN
                                [id] => 
                                [gender] => m
                            )
                    )

                [t_b] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [t_l] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [p_lev] => 2
                                [p_date] => 
                                [p_r] => 
                            )
                    )

                [t_r] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [I_r] => 19
                            )

                    )
```

// second array

```
 $bb = Array
                (
                    [t_a] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [f_c] => NAN
                                    [p_r] => RN
                                    [id] => 1214125
                                    [gender] => m
                                )
                        )

                    [t_b] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [t_l] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [p_lev] => 2
                                    [p_date] => 21
                                    [p_r] => 25
                                )
                        )

                    [t_r] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [I_r] => 19
                                )

                        )
```

I have used the array_diff function but i get NULL.

please some one help?

Comment: Your data is not arrays, they are objects. Convert them to arrays first.

Comment: how do i do that boss?

Comment: Depends of object themselves. You are referring to private property, so correct way is to launch the corresponding object's getter. A 'dirty' way is to use direct type cast, like this: `$rgData = (array)$objData`

Comment: i did that and i get array...now what?

Comment: I have update the code, please see it is Array now, but still the Array_filter is not working and neither the insert to mysql.

Comment: @MrInternet..you need to convert array format, it just object result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$aa=(array)$aa;
$bb=(array)$bb;
$result=array_diff($aa,$bb);
```

Comment: need to convert $aa and $bb into single array respectively

Comment: how do i convert to single array?

Comment: function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}

$aa=array_flatten($aa);
$bb=array_flatten($bb);

Comment: check this for above code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want. Please give an example or your desired output. Here's one possibility:

```
$ser_aa = array_map(function($e){return serialize($e);}, $aa);
$ser_bb = array_map(function($e){return serialize($e);}, $bb);
$diff = array_diff($ser_aa, $ser_bb);
$out = array_map(function($e){return unserialize($e);}, $diff);
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [t_a] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [f_c] => LAL
                    [p_r] => RN
                    [id] => 
                    [gender] => m
                )

        )

    [t_l] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [p_lev] => 2
                    [p_date] => 
                    [p_r] => 
                )

        )

)
```