# Convert an array of array into one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with my array, So my array is :

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sValue] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sValue] => 2
            )

    )
```

)
I want to get this array :

```
Array
(
  [0]=>1
  [1]=>2
)
```

I tried like this, but not work, it's get only the sValue = 1:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($aExpectedAnswers);$i++){
        foreach($aExpectedAnswers as $answer){
            $aFormatedAnswers[] = '\''.$answer[$i]['sValue'].'\'';
        }
    }
```

Help me please, Thx in advance

Comment: what is exact structure of your main array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert multidimensional array into single array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array)

Answer (score 4):

```
$aFormatedAnswers = [];
      foreach ($aExpectedAnswers as $answer) {
          if (is_array($answer)) {
             foreach ($answer as $item) {
              $aFormatedAnswers[] = $item;
              }
          } else {
           $aFormatedAnswers[] = $answer;
        }
```

Comment: In your `else` statement you want `$item` to be `$answer`

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = array();
foreach($initial as $subArray){
    foreach($subArrray as $value){
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$aExpectedAnswers = array(
    array(
     0 => array('sValue'=>1),
     1 => array('sValue'=>2),
    )
);

$result = array();
foreach($aExpectedAnswers as $aea){
    foreach($aea as $ae){
        $result[] = $ae['sValue'];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

hopefully helping.