# Convert nested array into string array for Doctrine where query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

Whats the simplest way to convert the following nested array into a simple array

```
array(
    'user' => array(
         'firstName' => 'Test',
         'lastName' => 'Test'
    ),
    'title' => 'Test'
)
```

Into

```
array(
    'user.firstName' => 'Test',
    'user.lastName' => 'Test',
    'title' => 'Test'
)
```

I need this format for a doctrine query where statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6785366/3675759

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$arr=array(
    'user' => array(
         'firstName' => 'Test',
         'lastName' => 'Test'
    ),
    'title' => 'Test'
);
$bigArr=array();
foreach($arr as $arK=>$arV){
    if(is_array($arr[$arK])){
        foreach($arr[$arK] as $k=>$v){
            $bigArr[$arK.".".$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    else{
        $bigArr[$arK]=$arV;
    }
}
var_dump($bigArr);
```

Output:-

```
array (size=3)
  'user.firstName' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  'user.lastName' => string 'Test' (length=4)
  'title' => string 'Test' (length=4)
```