# render HTML table from multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to extract data from a multidimensional array

```
       array(2) {
          ["label"]=>
          string(6) "label1"
          ["children"]=>
          array(3) {
            [1]=>
            array(1) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(6) "label2"
            }
            [2]=>
            array(1) {
              ["label"]=>
              string(6) "label3"
            }
           [3]=>
           array(2) {
             ["label"]=>
             string(6) "label4"
             ["children"]=>
             array(2) {
               [1]=>
               array(1) {
                 ["label"]=>
                 string(6) "label5"
               }
               [2]=>
               array(1) {
                 ["label"]=>
                 string(6) "label6"
               }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

into a table with the following structure:

```html
 <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <td colspan="4">label1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="1">label2</td>
       <td colspan="1">label3</td>
       <td colspan="2">label4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td colspan="1">label5</td>
       <td colspan="1">label6</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
```

The depth and structure of the array are dynamic, but the basic rule stays the same.

Any ideea on how I may accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the multidimensional array to a single and then loop through the single, creating the html string that you need, ie:

Convert the array:
see [Convert multidimensional array into single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array)

Loop through the single array in a php script and echo the string to your browser:

```
<?php
  function createHtml($singleArray){
    $html = '<table border="1">';
    foreach($singleArray as $label){
      $colspan = 1;
      //If then statement that sets $colspan based on label

      $html .= '<tr>';
      $html .= '<td colspan="'.$colspan.'">'.$label.'</td>';
      $html .= '</tr>';
    }
    $html .= '</table>';
    echo $html;
  }

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution only outputs one label per row (<table border="1"><tr><td colspan="1">label1</td></tr><tr><td colspan="1">Array</td></tr></table>). I need to have an arbitrary number of labels (<TD>s) per row, each with a "colspan" equal to the number of children in the array.