# Convert a Multidimensional array to single Dimension

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is the array as I currently have,please convert it to the below array with single dimensional array:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [is_custom] => yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [custom_amount] => 45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [custom_amount_text] => Enter Amount
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [amount_btn] => Dropdown
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [multiple_amounts] => W3sidGl0bGUiOiJMYWJlbCIsImFtb3VudCI6IjQ1In0seyJ0aXRsZSI6IkxhYmVsIiwiYW1vdW50IjoiNDU1In1d
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [recurring_plans] => W3sibmFtZSI6IkxhYmVsIiwicmVjdXJyaW5nX2Ftb3VudCI6Ijc4In0seyJuYW1lIjoidSIsInJlY3VycmluZ19hbW91bnQiOiI3ODgifV0=
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [recurring_interval] => WyJNb250aGx5IiwiUXVhcnRlcmx5IiwiSGFsZi1ZZWFybHkiXQ==
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [admin_mail_subject] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [admin_mail_body] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [user_mail_subject] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [user_mail_body] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [is_recurrance] => yes
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [is_onetime] => yes
        )

)
```

Now I want to convert this into something like this

```
Array([0]=> 
[is_custom] => yes 
[custom_amount] => 45 
[custom_amount_text] => Enter Amount 
[amount_btn] => Dropdown 
[multiple_amounts] => W3sidGl0bGUiOiJMYWJlbCIsImFtb3VudCI6IjQ1In0seyJ0aXRsZSI6IkxhYmVsIiwiYW1vdW50IjoiNDU1In1d
[recurring_plans] => W3sibmFtZSI6IkxhYmVsIiwicmVjdXJyaW5nX2Ftb3VudCI6Ijc4In0seyJuYW1lIjoidSIsInJlY3VycmluZ19hbW91bnQiOiI3ODgifV0=
)
```

Array 0 key will have all the keys can It be possible anyhow.I tried but failed.
Please help me with a possible solution

Comment: Check this answer. It's already answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array

Comment: That array have a same key [plan] but i dont have same key sir..

Comment: https://eval.in/669620

Comment: @Saini Try with accepted answer's code snippet. It will work regardless of your key variation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` for fast and simple.

```
$output_array = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($input_array)), 0); //$input_array-Replace your arrray

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => yes
    [1] => 45
    [2] => Enter Amount
    [3] => Dropdown
    [4] => W3sidGl0bGUiOiJMYWJlbCIsImFtb3VudCI6IjQ1In0seyJ0aXRsZSI6IkxhYmVsIiwiYW1vdW50IjoiNDU1In1d
    [5] => W3sibmFtZSI6IkxhYmVsIiwicmVjdXJyaW5nX2Ftb3VudCI6Ijc4In0seyJuYW1lIjoidSIsInJlY3VycmluZ19hbW91bnQiOiI3ODgifV0=
    [6] => WyJNb250aGx5IiwiUXVhcnRlcmx5IiwiSGFsZi1ZZWFybHkiXQ==
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => yes
    [12] => yes
)
```

**Run Yourself:**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86a50fd58455d64c4de074b888d5d2ea5ee1dd13

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$newArray=array_map(function($v){
return current($v);
},$oldArray);
```