# PHP : Convert Multi Dimensional Array to Single Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've an array like below: I want to make it single array format.

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
    )
 )
```

Would like to get output like below.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
    )
```

How can i achieve my preferred format ?? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: apply `foreach()` and get the sub-array value. BTW your question is bit unclear. Clarify a bit more pls

Comment: Both arrays are the same. Parents keys are `0` and `1` and they have sub arrays the same too.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, Both are not same, First one is Array within Array, second is that i want to achieve where only single array no parent array.

Comment: `$arr1 = $main[0]` and `$arr2 = $main[1]`? Where `$main` is the main array you have

Comment: Refer this stack overflow answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array

Another method is 
$array = array_column($array, 'plan');

down vote
$array = array_column($array, 'plan');
The first argument is an array  and the  second argument is array key.

Comment: You cant have multiple "single" arrays in 1 variable without a parent array, sorry just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

With a `foreach()` you can easily loop over it

```
<?php

$array = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 10],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]
    ];

foreach ($array as $smallArray)
{
    var_dump($smallArray);
}
```

[Try it out yourself here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bdecb78ddff1f6b0dd8beca8674e544bf4acfd8b)