# PHP Convert Multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array

```
$Old = [_1526906780329_329] => Array (
    [frlabel] => aa
    [enlabel] => AA
    )
[_1526906783640_640] => Array (
    [frlabel] => bb
    [enlabel] => BB
    )
```

I want `$old` array to convert it in single array key value format like

```
array('AA' => 'aa','BB' => 'bb');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert multidimensional array into single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array)

Comment: What code you used to do the convert and where you are getting struck?

Comment: @Sam Swift 웃 none of that answer solved my question which you suggest,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Old = [
    '_1526906780329_329' => [
        'frlabel' => 'aa',
        'enlabel' => 'AA',
    ],
    '_1526906783640_640' => [
        'frlabel' => 'bb',
        'enlabel' => 'BB',
    ],
];

$newArray = array_column($Old, 'frlabel', 'enlabel');
print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [AA] => aa
    [BB] => bb
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that usage of array_column.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 


    $final = array();
    $Old[_1526906780329_329] = Array (
        'frlabel' => 'aa',
        'enlabel' => 'AA',
        );

    $Old[_1526906783640_640] = Array (
        'frlabel' => 'bb',
        'enlabel' => 'BB',
        );

    foreach ($Old as $key => $value) {
        $final[$value['enlabel']] = $value['frlabel'];
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($final);
```

Comment: I have used this already :) @pyton has simpler method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is data specific...

```
$array1 = array();
$array1['frlabel'] = 'aa';
$array1['enlabel'] = 'AA';

$array2 = ['frlabel' => 'bb', 'enlabel' => 'BB'];

$old = array();
$old[] = $array1;
$old[] = $array2;
$result = array();

foreach($old as $tmp){
    $result[$tmp['enlabel']] = $tmp['frlabel'];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    ["AA"]=>
    string(2) "aa"
    ["BB"]=>
    string(2) "bb"
}
```