# Convert Multidimensional array to single array in codeigniter php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a multidimensional array as shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 237
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                 [id] => 228
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 247
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                 [id] => 238
                )
        )
)
```

I want to convert into single array as shown below

```
Array
(
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 237
        )
        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 228
        )
        [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 247
        )
        [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 238
        )
)
```

I have tried with the following solution [Convert multidimensional array into single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array)

But the result am not getting Its Coming Null

How to get the desired result for the above input.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try foreach loop then [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $value);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one works

```
function array_flattern($arr) {
    $returnArr=[];
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
        $returnArr = array_merge($returnArr, $v);
    }
    return $returnArr;
}
```