# How to convert single record array to ng-init format of AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using the php array to put in ng-init of AngularJS.

PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => admin
            [email] => admin@gmail.com
        )

)
```

AngularJS  ng-init:

How to convert the output to:

```
"username='admin';email='admin@gmail.com'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested but should work

```
function convert_array($arr){
    $tmp_arr=array();
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
        $tmp_arr[]=$key."='".$value."'";
    }
    return join(';',$tmp_arr)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code I need to convert into a single array first I use these code 

function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return FALSE; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } 
    else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}

from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array