# Laravel - Spreading an eloquent object into an array

Tags: php, laravel

Consider this code:

```
tokenArray = [
    $this->me(),
    'access_token' => $token,
    'token_type' => 'bearer',
    'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
];
```

and the output:

[image]

How can I have the properties in the userobject to be spread across in the $tokenArray?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6785366/11988937), it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the arrays.

```
$tokenArray = $this->me()->toArray() + [
    'access_token' => $token,
    'token_type' => 'bearer',
    'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
];
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Serializing Models and Collections - Serializing to Array](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays) `toArray`

[PHP Manual - Operators - Array Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) `+`

Comment: this doesn't actually work. `$this->me()` is basically returning `auth()->userOrFail()`.

Comment: @NewbieCoder updated earlier ... serializing the model to array with `toArray`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$obj = $this->me(),
```

The `$obj` is Object variable you some changes token array then get output I think this is correct:

```
tokenArray = [
    'id'  => $obj['0']->id
    'name'  => $obj['0']->name
    'username'  => $obj['0']->username
    'email'  => $obj['0']->email
    'access_token' => $token,
    'token_type' => 'bearer',
    'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
];
```

Another Method:

If you can use Eloquent method:

```
$obj = $this->me()->get()->toArray()

print_r($obj + $tokenArray);
```

This is Better for the Top answer.