# Multidimensionnal array to single one

Tags: php, arrays, post

Im struggling with a multidimensionnal array while building a form using ajax and PHP.
My ajax send a multidimensionnal array to php. And i want to convert this array to a single dimensionnal one.

so considering this code:

```
$reasons = $_POST['reasons'];
var_dump($reasons);
```

which output this:

```
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
            string(2) "37"
          ["reason"]=>
            string(9) "Something"
        }
   }
```

I now want it to be like this:

```
$reasons = {
  37 => "Something"
}
```

How can i do that ?
I have searched for hours and didn't find the right solution to do it...

What i have tried:

1)

```
function array_flatten($array) { 

    if (!is_array($array)) {
      return FALSE; 

    }

    $reasons = array(); 

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 

      if (is_array($value)) { 

        $reasons = array_merge($reasons, array_flatten($value)); 

      } else { 
        
        $reasons[$key] = $value; 
      
        }

    }

    return $reasons;

}

array_flatten($_POST['reasons']);

var_dump($reasons);

Output: NULL
```

2. 

```
$reasons = $_POST['reasons'];

$tabReasons = array_reduce($reasons, 'array_merge', array());

var_dump($tabReasons);
```

Output this:

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
    string(2) "37"
  ["reason"]=>
    string(9) "Parce que"
```

}

Which kind of work but my multidimenssional array can store multiple ID and Reasons. And when that happens, the code above only returns me a single pair of key & value

Like if i have two id and two reasons in my multidimenssional, it will only return me last id and reason into a single array...

i want something like : array(id => reason, id => reason, etc...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert multidimensional array into single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array)

Comment: _I have searched for hours and didn't find the right solution to do it_... please post your code, what you have tried?

Comment: I edited the code with everything i have tried and more explanations about what im trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_column()](https://php.net/array_column) to extract linear data of column, and [array_combine()](https://php.net/array_combine) to combine them as keys/values.

```
$reasons = [
    ['id' => 37, 'reason' => 'something'],
    ['id' => 38, 'reason' => 'something else'],
];
      
$indexed = array_combine(array_column($reasons, 'id'), array_column($reasons, 'reason'));

print_r($indexed);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [37] => something
    [38] => something else
)
```

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this

```
 function array_flatten($data) { 
         $res=array();
         foreach ($data as $val) { 
            $res[$val['id']] =$val['reason'];
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether your data are more complicated than shown here or not, but from the data provided it's quite straight forward to do.

```
$result = [
    $reasons[0]['id'] => $reasons[0]['reason']
];
```