# How to combine array of array values into one array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have following array,

```
Array
(
    [14289] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ability||STROKE CLINIC,Session||Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 2pm,child1||FC
            [1] => Ability||N/S++,Session||Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 2pm,child2||SC
            [2] => Ability||B-,Session||Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 2pm,child3||TC
        )

    [14279] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ability||STROKE CLINIC,Session||Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time||#1 only: 1pm,child1||FC
            [1] => Ability||N/S++,Session||Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time||#1 only: 1pm,child2||SC
            [2] => Ability||B-,Session||Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time||#1 only: 1pm,child3||TC
        )

    [14284] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ability||STROKE CLINIC,Session||Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 1:30pm,child1||FC
            [1] => Ability||N/S++,Session||Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 1:30pm,child2||SC
        )

)
```

i need this array as below,

```
Array
(


            [0] => Ability||STROKE CLINIC,Session||Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 2pm,child1||FC
            [1] => Ability||N/S++,Session||Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 2pm,child2||SC
            [2] => Ability||B-,Session||Session #3: Tues June 28th - Fri July 8th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 2pm,child3||TC
            [3] => Ability||STROKE CLINIC,Session||Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time||#1 only: 1pm,child1||FC
            [4] => Ability||N/S++,Session||Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time||#1 only: 1pm,child2||SC
            [5] => Ability||B-,Session||Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time||#1 only: 1pm,child3||TC          
            [6] => Ability||STROKE CLINIC,Session||Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 1:30pm,child1||FC
            [7] => Ability||N/S++,Session||Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time||#1 only: 1:30pm,child2||SC


)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $item);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) to merge the (sub-) arrays. This can be called via [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) for an easy interface:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

See as well:

- [PHP array merge from unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6747619/367456)
- [Convert multidimensional array into single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785355/convert-multidimensional-array-into-single-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_arr = array();
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item) use(&$new_arr)
{
    $new_arr[] = $item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your array is :

```
$z = array(
               '14289' =>
               array('a',
                     'b',
                     'c'
                    ),
               '14290' =>
               array('d',
                     'e',
                     'f'
                    ),
               '14291' =>
               array('g',
                     'h',
                     'i'
                    )
              );
```

then,

```
$y =array();// use a blank array to get your result
array_map(function($a) use(&$y){ $y = array_merge( $y,array_values($a)); },$z);

var_dump($y);
```